# List of heritability estimates in humans?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, genetics, human-genetics, human-genome

Many people on this site ask questions that directly or indirectly have to do with heritability in human.

**Do you know a list of estimates of heritability of various traits in humans? Or could you try to create such list?**

That might be great to have various kind of traits, personality traits, life-history traits, morphological traits, …

I am not necessarily asking for [GWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study) studies that inform about what genes explain the observed variance (although that would be really great) but just some estimates of heritability and eventually information about the method used (parent-offspring regression, twins, ...) and which population was studied.

Comment: Do you think about a list of traits (for example hair color) and genes associated to it?

Comment: @Chris I did not expect something as accurate as the results of a GWAs. I was just thinking about a list of values of heritability for a list of traits. If one wants to add the way it's been measure, on which population and if it is a GWAs, give more info about what genes and how many genes explain the variance then it is really really cool but I will accept the answer even if it is not that perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider consulting the [H2DB](http://tga.nig.ac.jp/h2db/) database. The database is quite new, so the number of heritability estimates is not very high at the moment (currently 225 estimates for human, 838 estimates in total), but it's a start. The database is described in a paper by Kaminuma et al.([2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23193255))